# how to obfuscate single string into .net assembly

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I wonder if it's possible obfuscate only some strings from your source code into generated assembly file. My goal is create a checksum using salt string and I'd like hardcode salt string into my assembly avoiding that string will be visible in case somebody will disassembly mys ddl. I'm not interested into a full assembly obfuscation, only some strings

Comment: Don't think that obfuscating only part of it is useful. The big problem with reversing is the size of the haystack in which you search the needle. To break what you indent to do I'd just locate the code where you use the salt, put a breakpoint on it and check what value it has after you de-obfuscated the string.

Comment: Are you generating a checksum or a cryptographic hash? If it's a checksum then an attacker can trivially obtain the salt; if it's a cryptographic hash then the salt does not need to be secret. Can you explain why you need to keep the salt secret?

Comment: I'd guess to detect tempering of data files. Local high-score files of games come to my mind as one application. Obviously a skilled attacker can manipulate them, but it stops somebody who just knows how to use a hex editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it matter? The deobfuscator would have to be built into your assembly as well, otherwise you couldn't get the string back. Someone looking at your assembly would only need run the deobfuscator to get your salt string. If you really want to hide a string, put it into a native assembly.

Comment: "native assembly" do you mean create an assembly in C++ instead of in C# which contains set of string I'd like to keep hide and use the assembly/string from my C# assembly?

Comment: Yes. You could even consider performing your hash function within the native DLL and using `SecureString` in .NET so that it is not visible in memory.